# Name misspelled in visa status update notice

Tags: visas, application-status

I applied for a German Schengen visa in Delhi via VFS [its a global agency coordinating visa process in India]. All my details are correct in the application form and passport but, when I received a status email from VFS for my application, I found that my name was not spelled correctly in the salutation. Then I noticed that, in payment receipt, my applicant name is  misspelt in same way as in the email. It seems the agent collecting my application had typed name incorrectly.

My application is still processing but I am worried now whether the same incorrent name will be copied onto the visa or it be taken from the application form?

And, in case my name is not spelled correctly on the visa, what options will I have and how long does it take to rectify this?

Further Update:

I called up VFS today and they said the name in email or receipt issued is just for VFS tracking purpose. Name printed on Visa will be taken from application form. So hopefully things should be fine but still lets see how it goes.

Comment: It is something that should be corrected at the earliest stage possible. Have the VFS email them, or you email them or fax them. Adding 'application-status' tag because it's a type of 'post-submission anxiety'

Comment: @GayotFow: I will be calling up VFS on Monday. On one side i feel that embassy will check details only on passport and application form and will put name on Visa stamp themselves but then i don't know how it works. Lets see, it really frustration that somebody's mistake will make me run around to get things fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got my visa with correct name. So here is how it works.

1. Name on receipt given by VFS is just for tracking purpose and doesn't impact your visa. But remember the same name get printed on courier sent by VFS, so you may have trouble with courier when they ask ID proof.
2. Visa stamping is done based on details in application form and passport.

Thanks all for help and suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Better safe than sorry. Contact the embassy (preferrably via VFS, because they should admit the error was on their part and that you had no intention to mislead). I am aware of 2 cases where (a) the traveler's name was misspelled on the visa but there were no hiccups during travel, and (b) the spelling error resulted in a traveller being refused entry.

So this needs to be tackled ASAP.